# Getting string items around a set string of characters?

Tags: vb.net

Ok I am on the last part of this part of my project... If I have a strings like:

```
 James Williams 432 Co Rd 1 Cullman Al 35055
 Or     
 James Williams 432 Co Rd 12 Cullman Al 35055 
 Or
 James Williams 432 Co Rd 123 Cullman Al 35055 
 Or
 James Williams 432 Co Rd 1234 Cullman Al 35055
```

which those numbers could be anything from 0 to 9.. How can I assign the CR and the number(s) immediately after to a string value????

I am having to parse address information out of a file... The parser works fine for addresses that do not contain a CR which means County Road. So I am thinking I can strip the address part out of the string I am passing into the parser by using something like..

```
  Dim _holder as string = {Gets a value I can track already in the current Function}
  DIM _Address as string = Nothing
  IF _holder.contains("Co Rd") Then
      _Address = { "Numbers just before Co Rd" + " " + "Co Rd" + "Numbers Just after Co Rd"}
  End If
```

Comment: I can't decipher this.  What are you trying to do?  Can you post a before and after or something.  BTW, what have you tried?

Comment: @LarsTech: It sounds like he wants a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on how valid your data is, but here is a quick example:

```
Private Function ExtractAddressWithCoRd(ByVal input As String) As String
  Dim add1 As String = String.Empty
  Dim add2 As String = String.Empty

  Dim parts() As String = input.Split(" "c)
  For i As Integer = 0 To parts.Length - 1
    If parts(i) = "Co" AndAlso i > 0 Then
      add1 = parts(i - 1)
    ElseIf parts(i) = "Rd" AndAlso i < parts.Length - 1 Then
      add2 = parts(i + 1)
    End If
  Next

  Return add1 + " Co Rd " + add2
End Function
```

Comment: this does not work says object not set to an instance of an object. When it hits Dim parts() as string = input.Split(" "c) any ideas???

Comment: @Skindeep2366 What value are you passing for input?  Make sure it isn't a null value from your calling source.